How to find the orientation of a circular polarizer without reference polarizers or molecules
It's my first time using this website, I really need your help to solve something. Also, english is not my first language so I'm sorry if I write nonsense stuff. My professor made a challange for the class to solve; basically he asked to "describe a procedure to determinate the orientation of a circular polarizer". He said we can use up to 3 circular polarizers of unknown orientation. If necessary we can use a mirror or light filters (colored paper), that's all. We cannot use any reference polarizer which orientation is known, nor use reflection and transmission in a chiral material. It's been a few days and nobody in my class made any progress, I talked to a few veterans and one of them suggested me to ask for help on this website. So, after all, does this have a possible solution? Thank you for your attention!

Is this done in the dark, or do you get a light source on the equipment list? If the light is ambient, does it include the blue sky?

It's not necessarily to make it in the dark, my professor wasn't specific about it, all the information he gave to us I just wrote above. So I guess it's viable to use some light source, or even just use the ambient light, which includes the blue sky.

What do you mean by orientation? If its right-handed or left-handed? The orientation of the linearly polarized light if you turn it around? The $\lambda/4$ surface and the linear polarizer surface?

Sorry for the delay, and yes, by the orientation I mean right-handed / left-handed. I want to know if the circular polarizer is right-handed or left-handed.

@Beatriz Maybe put some effort here, and let us know how circular polarizers work (are they 2 way, or one way optical devices?), and whether CP is flipped on reflection (I think it is, but don't want to derive it). Anything I google comes up with 1/4 wave plates and devices not allowed in the problem.

@Beatriz the point about blue sky is that it provides a source of multiple linear polarized light, meanwhile, a laser can have a known CP, so the problem is trivial. With an unpolarized source, the answer is either 'no' or really tricky.
